# How to add background timer?

Tags: python, function, loops, time, background-process

I am making a program in python that runs forever in an infinite loop something like this:

```
import time
seconds=0
while True:
    seconds+=1
    print(seconds,' seconds passed')
    time.sleep(1)
```

**What I want to achive**

1. I want to run the clock in background
2. I want to keep track of the time, for example after 24 hours of running the code I want to call `exit()`

I don't know anything about background processes, any of the above 2 answers will be acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to

1. I want to run the clock in background

You should look into multithreading which allows you to run programs in the background on a different thread. Simply import thread.

2. I want to keep track of the time, for example after 24 hours of running the code I want to call exit()

I would add

```
 print(time.ctime(time.time()) )
```

at the end of your for loop to get the time in 24 hour periods.

Comment: Check out this link on tutorials point for more detail. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm